# Building Release and Debug targets at once for eclipse CDT with cmake

Tags: eclipse, cmake, target

How do I create `Release` and `Debug` targets for a single project at the same time with cmake for my eclipse CDT?
For now my `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
...
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0 -g" )
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O2" )
```

With this, I can hit either the `Debug` or `Release` configuration for my in-source project:

```
$ cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
$ cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
```

I know, that I can create out-of-source builds by using sibling folders with different configuration, but then I have two different projects in my eclipse.
In my scenario I just want to have one project with different targets.

This [site](http://sgpsproject.sourceforge.net/JavierVGomez/index.php/How_to_configure_a_C/C%2B%2B_project_with_Eclipse_and_CMake) explains how to this manually, but is there an autogenerated way?

Comment: I don't think its possible to have both build types in the same directory. How should the flags be set? How to distinguish which you want? I'd suggest to run your cmake command whenever you want to change. It should go fast and is transparent for the user.

Comment: @usr1234567 cmake creates a bunch of targets with each project. Shouldn't there be a possibility to add a prefix to a set of targets, to get to this point?
Another fact: The manual solution does work, so why shouldn't there be an automized way?

Comment: What do you mean with the manual version works? If you rerun cmake, it will overwrite the last configuration, doesn't it?

Comment: @usr1234567 With the manual version I wanted to refer to the given link (last text passage from my post).
I know that I can rerun cmake and reopen eclipse, so this is not the question here.
Just, how can I add multiple targets via cmake.

Comment: As I understand from different inet links, `Eclipse` cmake generator **doesn't support multiple configurations**. Eclipse himself wraps single-configuration builds into project with several configurations(*Make targets* in its terminology). This wrapping operates with two(or more) different CMake builds, and both these builds cannot be in-source ones.